# Is it still possible to recover Multibit Classic wallet from multibit.key file?

Tags: multibit, recover-private-key, lost-wallet

I have the file mulibit.key (long string starting with `U2FsdGVkX19E+pw`) and password.
Cannot find the Multibit Classic wallet to import the key and export to Electrum...

Tried to decrypt the key with

`openssl enc -d -p -aes-256-cbc -a -in multibit.key -out key.txt -pass pass:Mypassword`

but got only such response:

```
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
salt=44FA9C205936F29D
key=8E260D08EE31BB97AB7544D70BC41535369
iv =B6B2A8A90712B2393DDF8
bad decrypt
140404139345280:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:588
```

EDIT WITH FULL ANSWER:

The problem was different version of open ssl... After adding flag `-md md5` my multibit.key get encrypted! So I could enter the private key into Electrum wallet

`openssl enc -d -p -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -a -in multibit.key  -out key.txt  -pass 'pass:myPassword'`

Comment: No. The links are not working any more...

Comment: Can you find the multibit classic ("Multibit") in your hard drive or should I send you my copy of Multibit 0.5.16? The former is better since it doesn't require that you trust me.

Comment: Or you can download it from https://linux.softpedia.com/get/Office/Finance/MultiBit-102886.shtml . The file is `multibit-0.5.18-linux.jar` but it works on all operating systems

Comment: It seems to me those links do work, they just redirect to a github repository for the source code to Multibit Classic.

Comment: Thank you @MCCCS . Managed to decrypt the key without Multibit wallet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try the -md5 flag, the openssl decryption changed a few years back and the md5 flag should solve it

Comment: YES!! That did the job!! it was -md flag: `openssl enc -d -p -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -a -in multibit.key  -out key.txt  -pass 'pass:myPassword'`